# No connection between Android and PC

Tags: android, usb, adb, driver, mtp

I've been struggling with this problem for several months trying to solve it but with no success.

I am not able to connect any Android device to the PC (Mass storage or ADB) beside Samsung phones without hacking or using different drivers (only manually installed).

I have this problem with Sony, Nexus, HTC and more China Android phones.

I tried to use the default USB driver(ADB interface), delivered with the phone, but windows cannot install it since it doesn't see that driver compatible with my device. I hacked the driver by inserting the hardware IDs in the driver's .inf file. This way every phone is being installed but this way some phones work, others don't (ADB).
For the mass storage mode, I somehow managed to install every phone as Portable Devices / MTP Device and this way works, I can browse through the folders, without having access to ADB.

This problem is not reproducible on another PC; when the phone is connected for the first time, it appears as a mass storage device in My computer, without any effort. If I give the default driver, the phone is ready to be exploited via ADB also.

It's very frustrating to install / uninstall drivers depending on your need dozens of times per day, without knowing for sure if it'll work.

Please, if you know any tips how can I solve this, I'll be very grateful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Which Windows version are you running on? What's the name of your computer model? Is your computer beyond a proxy? Are you sure it's not the usb cable that is not the problem?

Comment: It used to work perfectly, the problem is happening since January this year. Windows 7 Enterprise, I changed 5 USB cables, still no change. Sony phones aren't even charging when connected to the USB. Still, no problem with Samsung...

I thought this might be a conflicted-drivers problem... I used a tool to uninstall all the drivers installed manually or automatically for every device inserted in the USB ports and install them again. Still no sign of light

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first you need adb drivers installed on your computer. Then you should search in Device Manager (you can open it from your System properties window - right click on "My computer" -> "Properties") for reqired device with yellow sign (don't forget to check "USB Debugging" is enabled on your phone!).  Right click -> "Update drivers" -> "Search on my computer" -> **"Choose from already installed drivers"**. Choose "Android ADB Interface" and click "Next". With this way I can use any device for debugging with my

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Any advice where can I find that pack of ADB drivers?

Comment: My collegue gave me his Huawei phone with drivers in its internal storage. He said using their "ADB driver" is fine for any device. You can install it for Huawei in a normal way (with auto searching in a folder with drivers). After that you can use them in a way described in my answer for any other device.
You can download drivers I used from my storage: http://voronov.tsk.ru/adb/